# Program or Application to replace http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Tags: html, unicode, hex, character, converters

Looks like this guy's site is offline or unresponsive.
I used to use this daily.
If anyone has an app or program that is free or nearly free they can recommend that would be super awesome.

Thank you in advance.
{EDIT}
What I am looking for is a unicode character conversion utility. Apologies I take it for granted that people are familiar with this online tool as it is super helpful and was Number 1 on google when you searched for character conversion or unicode conversion.

Comment: so you're asking people to help you find a replacement for a tool that's offline without telling people what it did...??

Comment: @Eonasdan I understand  you question and I agree, I should have posted up that I needed a character conversion tool. Thank you.

Comment: Go and Stackoverflow sin no more, my son `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that the tool is all javascript based so you could just go [the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20131229023147/http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) and save the page or download it etc